# iftop - how to find these ports related process

Tags: linux, process, monitoring

On the most left column, there are the processes with ports running on my server. I got this by running : `iftop -i eth0 -P`.

[image]

Some of the ports I can easily find out which process/application it is. But there are some, I cound not find out by using `netstat -anlp|grep <PORT>` or `ps -ef|grep <PORT>`.

So, my question is how can I find out those 'temporary' ports relates to which processes running on my server?

Answer (score 1):

we can find the related process by running `lsof | grep <port number>`.

The output of the lsof command contains pid, by which, `ps -ef|grep <pid>`, we can find out which process this is.